# in Qlikview, is possible to do a "strict fields" concatenate?

Tags: performance, concatenation, qlikview

i have been using qlikview for a few years by now and a simple problem i face almost daily is the need to concatenate tables with different fields when i only need some of them.

For example lets say i have the following tables on separated QVDs

table1:

[image]

table2:

[image]

i need to make a final table with field_1, field_2 and field_3 ONLY, but if i do

[image]

i get an error that field_2 doesn't exists on table2. i can put null() as field_2 when im dealing with a small amount of tables where i know the field doesn't exists, but when i'm iterating over 500+ QVDs where some have the field and some not i need a way to determine this.

right now i have two ways of solving this problem:

1. i'm loading the qvd first with a * and using FIELDNUMBER to see if the field exists and the putting the field in a variable to use at load time.

example:

[image]

2. i'm creating an empty starter table with the fields set to null and concatenating to that with a load * so the missing fields gets generated (taking advantage of the "generate missing fields with null")

example:

[image: Screenshot from 2020-09-02 20-48-43.png]

this is quite bad performance-wise as i'm loading the entire file to memory when i'm only interested in a few columns and then need to drop them later.

is there a way to make a concatenate that only take the columns already present in the first table, completes with null the missing columns but auto-exclude all the other not required fields?

i tried using a preceding load before loading with *, but it fails when one of the fields is not on the qvd. any ideas?

P.S.: i know that the ways i described solve the problem, but i'm looking for a better solution, performance and speed wise.

Answer (score 0):

When concatenating two tables in Qlik there is no need for the fields to match. You can even concatenate two tables with completely different fields and Qlik will not complain. Qlik will just add `null` for the fields that are missing.

Looking at the script below - we have two tables `Table1` and `Table2`.

- `Table1`'s fields: `field1`, `field2`, `field3`
- `Table2`'s fields: `field3`, `field4`, `field5`

When load all fields from `Table1` and concatenate only `field3` from `Table2` the result will be:

[image]

`field1` and `field2` are populated with `null` for the rows which are sourced from `Table2`

```
Table1:
Load * Inline [
  field1, field2, field3
  1     , 2     , 3     
  4     , 5     , 6
];

Table2:
Load * Inline [
  field3, field4, field5
  1     , 2     , 3
  4     , 5     , 6
];

NoConcatenate


ConcatenatedTable:
Load
  field1,
  field2,
  field3
Resident
  Table1
;

Concatenate

Load
  field3
Resident
  Table2
;

Drop Tables Table1, Table2;
```

Comment: thx for the anwser, maybe i didn't express myself correctly: i know that forced concatenate generate missing fields in null (i use it on my second example). my problem is when i have 500 qvd with f1, f2, f3, f4, etc and want to concatenate ONLY [f1 f2 f3] but some of the tables doesn't have f2 and i can't know in advance which ones are, i end up either preloading every qvd to check if the field exists or force concatenating the entire file to an empty table. both solutions i dislike because i end loading in memory way more data that what i really need and loosing performance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach, I don't have a dataset big enough to test it's performance, but at least solves the problem of having explicit field names in the script, which could be a nightmare to maintain.

Start by loading all the files using a CrossTable, to deconstruct the structure :

```
for each file in FileList('<folder>\<files>*')

   RawTable:
   CrossTable(Field, Data, 2)
   LOAD FileName() as FileName,
         RowNo() as RowId,
         *
   FROM
    [$(file)]
    (txt, utf8, no labels, embedded labels, delimiter is ',');

next file;
```

This will create a table containing 4 fields : the original filename (FileName), the rownumber inside that file (RowId), the name of the column (Field) and it's value (Data).

Then bootstrap your final table to contain reference to every file and every row known :

```
DataTable:
LOAD
    DISTINCT FileName,
    RowId
Resident RawTable;
```

Then create a support table with the distinct name of every known field in your files :

```
FieldTable:
LOAD
    Distinct Field as KnownField 
Resident RawTable;
```

Finally the magic begins, where you go field by field left join them to the DataTable :

```
LET NumFields = NoOfRows('FieldTable');

FOR i = 0 to $(NumFields) - 1
    LET vField = Peek('KnownField', $(i), 'FieldTable');

    TRACE $(vField);

    Left Join(DataTable)
    LOAD
        FileName,
        RowId,
        Data as $(vField)
    Resident RawTable
    WHERE Field = '$(vField)';  
NEXT;
```

Finally just some clean up :

```
DROP TABLE RawTable;
DROP TABLE FieldTable;
```

If you want to keep just a subset of the fields, you can filter then when creating the FieldTable.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i use a similar logic when i don't know the fieldnames of the datasets loading and want to match them with a list of possible fieldnames; but since FOR-lines in qlikview are incredibly low-performance i prefer to avoid them when i can. the examples i gave already work, i'm just trying to see if there's a more performant way to do it

Answer (score 0):

For a more performant solution, you can fetch each qvd's meta data first to get its containing fields and then setup your qvd iteration logic based on this.

Here is the main script that gives you fieldnames of a qvd file:

```
LOAD
    "FieldName"
FROM [some.qvd]
(XmlSimple, table is [QvdTableHeader/Fields/QvdFieldHeader]);
```

Comment: i thought about doing that, but it's the same as loading the file and using fieldnumber to check, which means i end up reading twice the same file from disk. i know i'm trying to gain a 0.5% performance boost by going out of my way in weird/occult code, but i had to ask